# How can I run rsync over ssh via a http web interface to initiate rsync to move files from server2 to server1

Tags: php, rsync

**Scenario:**

We have pdf files on server2 named by ticket number, i.e. 2543675.pdf, due to users making mistakes with renaming the files correctly and causing imports to get stuck, I have been tasked with renaming these files automatically via a web interface with just one button click to initiate the renaming of files to format  ticketnumber_customerNumber_customerName.pdf. In order for me to do that, I need to move/rsync the files from server2 to server1. Extract the base name from pdf file  which is the customer number, run a query against customer ticket table in some database and rename the files with the data I get from the tickets table. Once done, I move/rsync the files back to server1 with rsync where the files are then uploaded/imported by an automated system that expects them to be named properly or the process will fail and halt the work flow.

Test Environment using Virtualbox VMs:

**server1 192.168.1.2**   Centos 7 - Hosting web interface for rsync

**server2 192.168.1.3**   Ubunutu 10 - Hosting SMB share with pdf 

**workstation 192.168.1.100**   Workstation invoking php script via web page

What I've tried:
**Server1**
1. Generated ssh keys and copied them to remote server server2 for automatic authentication via key. Used ssh-copy-id
2. Copied ssh keys to **/opt/www-files** directory on server1
3. Changed owner to **apache:apache** for /opt/www-files on server1
4. Current access to directory www-files 755, files id_rsa 600, id_rsa.pub 644
5. Ran web interface readFiles2.php and it didn't work when running script. I get an error in apache log:

```
[Fri Aug 03 12:54:16.432825 2018] [:error] [pid 1670] [client 192.168.1.100:40808] PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to 192.168.1.3 on port 22 in /var/www/html/readFiles2.php on line 20
[Fri Aug 03 12:54:16.432886 2018] [:error] [pid 1670] [client 192.168.1.100:40808] PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to 192.168.1.3 in /var/www/html/readFiles2.php on line 20
[Fri Aug 03 12:54:16.432910 2018] [:error] [pid 1670] [client 192.168.1.100:40808] PHP Warning:  ssh2_fingerprint() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/readFiles2.php on line 21
[Fri Aug 03 12:54:16.432920 2018] [:error] [pid 1670] [client 192.168.1.100:40808] PHP Warning:  ssh2_auth_pubkey_file() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/readFiles2.php on line 22
[Fri Aug 03 12:54:16.432960 2018] [:error] [pid 1670] [client 192.168.1.100:40808] PHP Warning:  ssh2_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/readFiles2.php on line 27
[Fri Aug 03 12:54:16.432970 2018] [:error] [pid 1670] [client 192.168.1.100:40808] PHP Warning:  ssh2_fetch_stream() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/html/readFiles2.php on line 28
[Fri Aug 03 12:54:16.432986 2018] [:error] [pid 1670] [client 192.168.1.100:40808] PHP Warning:  stream_set_blocking() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/html/readFiles2.php on line 30
[Fri Aug 03 12:54:16.432997 2018] [:error] [pid 1670] [client 192.168.1.100:40808] PHP Warning:  stream_set_blocking() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/html/readFiles2.php on line 31
[Fri Aug 03 12:54:16.433010 2018] [:error] [pid 1670] [client 192.168.1.100:40808] PHP Warning:  stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/html/readFiles2.php on line 34
[Fri Aug 03 12:54:16.433019 2018] [:error] [pid 1670] [client 192.168.1.100:40808] PHP Warning:  stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/html/readFiles2.php on line 36
[Fri Aug 03 12:54:16.433043 2018] [:error] [pid 1670] [client 192.168.1.100:40808] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/html/readFiles2.php on line 42
[Fri Aug 03 12:54:16.433051 2018] [:error] [pid 1670] [client 192.168.1.100:40808] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/html/readFiles2.php on line 43
```

6. if I run readFiles1.php from web interface a I get an unexplained error in apache but if I run this script from the console as root, it works fine. Files are transferred back and forth depending on which command I run within the script.

   Apache Error:

```
    ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.3 port 22: Permission denied
    rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
    rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

**Server's File Layout**

```
Server1
/
├── opt
│   └── www-files
│       ├── id_rsa
│       └── id_rsa.pub
│   
├── var
│   └── www
│       └── html
│           ├── files
│           ├── readFiles1.php
│           └── readFiles2.php
```

```
Server2
/
├── srv
│   └── pdfs
│       ├── 2534566.pdf
│       ├── 2456345.dpf
│       ├── 2643123.pdf
│       ├── 2456256.pdf
│       ├── 2789023.pdf
│       ├── 2567454.pdf
│       ├── 2876430.pdf
.           .
.           .
.           .
```

Script: **readFiles1.php**

```
<?php

function readFiles($dir){
   if(is_dir($dir)){
      if($dh=opendir($dir)){
         while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false){
            echo "Filename: ".$file."<br>";  
         }
         closedir($dh);
      }
   }
}

//$cmd = 'rsync -av --ignore-existing --remove-source-files /var/www/html/files/* root@192.168.1.3:/srv/pdfs/';

$cmd = "rsync -av --ignore-existing --remove-source-files root@192.168.1.3:/srv/pdfs/ /var/www/html/files/";
shell_exec($cmd);

$dir_source = "./files/";
readFiles($dir_source);

?>
```

Script: **readFiles2.php** Found this script on the web, had to install some dependencies.

```
<?php
include('/usr/share/pear/Net/SSH2.php');

function readFiles($dir){
   if(is_dir($dir)){
      if($dh=opendir($dir)){
         while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false){
            echo "Filename: ".$file."<br>";  
         }
         closedir($dh);
      }
   }
}


function runRemoteSSH($command){
    $connection = ssh2_connect('192.168.1.3');
    $ssh_key = ssh2_fingerprint($connection);
    ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, 'root','/opt/www-files/id_rsa.pub','/opt/www-files/id_rsa');

    $log = array();
    $log[] = "Sending command: ".$command;
    $log[] = "--------------------";
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
    $streamError = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);

    stream_set_blocking($streamError, true);
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

    $log[] = "output of command: ";
    $log[] = stream_get_contents($stream);
    $log[] = "------------------";
    $error = stream_get_contents($stream);
    if(strlen($error) > 0 ){
       $log[] = 'Error occured:';
       $log[] = $error;
       $log[] = "--------";         
    }   
    fclose($streamError);
    fclose($stream);
}
//$cmd = 'rsync -av --ignore-existing --remove-source-files /var/www/html/files/* root@192.168.1.3:/srv/pdfs/';

$cmd = "rsync -av --ignore-existing --remove-source-files root@192.168.1.3:/srv/pdfs/ /var/www/html/files/";
runRemoteSSH($cmd);


$dir_source = "./files/";
readFiles($dir_source);

?>
```

Script 3(**readFiles3.php**): Gets files from local SMB share, works fine here since no ssh connection is needed.

```
<?php


function readFiles($dir){
   if(is_dir($dir)){
      if($dh=opendir($dir)){
         while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false){
            if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
                $list = explode(".",$file);             
                $source_file = "./files/".$file;
                $target_file = "./files/".$list[0]."_custno_custname.".$list[1];
                echo "Renaming file[$source_file] to [$target_file]<br>";
                rename($source_file, $target_file); 
            }
         }
         closedir($dh);
      }
   }
}
$cmd = "rsync -av --ignore-existing --remove-source-files /srv/smb/tickets/ /var/www/html/files";
echo "Getting files....<br>";
shell_exec($cmd);
$dir_source = "./files/";
readFiles($dir_source);
echo "Moving files back....<br>";
$cmd = "rsync -av --ignore-existing --remove-source-files /var/www/html/files/ /srv/smb/tickets/ ";
shell_exec($cmd);
?>
```

Comment: So, from my perspective - I would use shell scripts to do the work load, and invoke those from PHP, rather than PHP running rsync and performing all these tasks more well suited to BASH. I also would be concerned about security implications of giving PHP so much access.  Additionally, is PHP running as apache, a virtualhost user, or hopefully not in any way - root.

Comment: Yes, apache runs as user "apache" that is why it probably fails. I will try the bash script. I will create it in the /var/www/cgi-bin directory. Thanks.

Comment: bash script get.sh with two lines, 1: #!/bin/bash 2. rsync -av --ignore-existing --remove-source-files root@192.168.1.3/srv/pdfs/ /var/www/html/files/ works fine when invoked from console via php script, php getFiles.php, it works fine. .but if I run it from web interface it gives me error Host key verification failed.

Comment: you have the right SSH keys setup for the user running the script and the public keys added to the opposite servers "authorized_hosts" file?

Comment: Yes, keys are correct for both servers but rsync changes my destination folder rights and I can't rename files. Tried different things but we decided to go with script 3 and create a local SMB share instead.

Comment: You may also find that you run into the the php time limit too for processing, depending on how long all this takes.